# How do you cancel all touch actions in progress?

Tags: ios

I'm facing a situation in where I have 2 buttons that show different view controllers when tapped.

The problem is that if I press and hold down "button 1" and then press and release on "button 2" and then release "button 1" both button actions are executed. (In this case presenting a view controller)

So I thought that the simplest solution would be to call something on the same place as I am presenting my view controller that would "cancel all touches in action, or all the user interaction" so that when the button that was being pressed down is release it wouldn't register it as a new event.

Is there a method in iOS used to "interrupt" all touches in progress?

Comment: I think, you will get some help by looking at responder chain. [UIResponder Reference](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiresponder)

Comment: @Chiquis : Why dont you block the userInteraction of the View containing two buttons when a first button tap is detected :) That way only one button can be tapped and once the button released/intended action of button done re-enable the user interaction :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go,
this will make only one button clickable at a time

```
for (UIView * button in [self.view subviews]) {
    if([button isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
        [((UIButton *)button) setExclusiveTouch:YES];
}
```

A **better** solution is to make a **Category** for `UIButton` and set this code in it :

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib];
    [self setExclusiveTouch:YES];
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I needed.